# LENGTH Equivalent in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0, string-length

I am building a report in Report Builder 3.0 and require spacing that is conditional on the length of a parameter. Because Report Builder 3.0 does not have the LENGTH function that it did in 1.0, is there a workaround? I want to avoid solutions that white-out text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure the lenght of a string using the LEN function 
e.g.

```
= Len(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value)
```

An alternative is to use the string length property

```
= Parameters!ReportParameter1.value.Length
```